# Node Convert Image URL to data:image using streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I currently have an endpoint which is used to circumvent CORS that takes in any image URL and returns the contents in data-uri format. This works well, but I think it would be much more efficient to use a streaming solution where the response is built as a stream from the image request.

Here is the working, non-stream version:

```
  app.get('/api/image/convert', function (req, res) {
    // TODO: use request piping for significantly more efficient throughput
    request.get(req.query.url, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response && response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300) {
        var data = "data:" + response.headers["content-type"] + ";base64," + new Buffer(body).toString('base64')
        res.send(data)
      } else {
        res.send((response && response.statusCode) || 500, error)
      }
    })
  })
```

My question is would it be more efficient to pipe the request.get to the result and, if so, how would this look?

Thanks!

Comment: The one missing line fwiw is: var request = require('request').defaults({ encoding: null })

Answer (score 0):

I've try this with google maps example, and it works

```
var request = require('request');
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap" +
        "&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G;%7C40.711614,-74.012318" +
        "&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284&sensor=false";

request.get(url).pipe(res);
});
```

[github:request](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

Comment: This is definitely what I'm going for; I think the only difference in my case is that the pipe needs to apply a transform to the request data before returning the response.